# Как подсчитать поле lot со значением Enum '1'?

Tags: php, yii2

```
$lots = Post::find()->where(['lot'=>'1'])->count();
```

Comment: Решено:   $postCount = Post::find()->where(['lot'=>'1'])->count();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lots = Post::find()->where(['lot' => 1])->asArray()->count(); //вернет счетчик 
$lots = Post::find()->where(['lot' => 1])->asArray()->all(); // если нужно для foreach()
```

Answer (score 0):

Структуру таблицы покажите, но если взять что у вас `lot` колонка в таблице `Post` тогда должно быть вот так:

```
$lots = Post::find()->where(['lot' => 1])->find()->asArray();
```

Comment: Обновленный вариант пробовали?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Так вы же сумму хотели. Изменил чтоб на выходе был массив

Comment: Да сумму мне нужно, сколько единиц всего, в поле lot.